# Add button to existing standardController page SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I want to add a button to an existing SalesForce object page that already has a standardController and page built by salesforce.
I have a utility class that I want to call a function by a button on my object.

Currently, I only have seen ways of doing this by a WebService, which I included the code snippets below.  I am thinking there has to be another way, due to the fact I want to reuse this code in other places that do not require a webservice, and I want to avoid writing two procedures for same thing.  I know I could use a wrapper I guess, but want to see if there is another way of adding a button that is more in line with the new salesforce way of visualpages, and not s-controls/web services.

So, when I add a button on the salesforce page by going to setup-->create-->objects then scroll down to add a button, it requires that the button be an scontrol or javascript.  I found this technique

```
Apex code:


global class class1{
WebService static Integer method1(String iTitle){

 Your logic here

}

}


Custom button code:

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/apex.js")}


var result = sforce.apex.execute("class1", "method1",{iTitle : noteTitle});
```

Comment: What is the function you're trying to call? its not clear here whether that's already in apex or not. If you method is in apex you can override a standard button with a visualforce page to call it as long as that page uses the standard controller... but its really hard to know what this function is or where it is without additional detail.

Comment: I figured it out myself,
    <apex:detail subject="{!CustomObject.Id}" relatedList="true" />    did the trick on formatting the page i intended.